自作のライブラリ側で main() 関数を用意して、利用側では定義不要にする実装方法が知りたい
質問内容
以下のソースコードですが、core::Loop()関数を利用側で定義してライブラリ側でmain()関数を定義することで利用側でmain()の記述を不要にしたいのですが以下のエラーが出てしまい、どのように実装すればいいのかわかりません。
知りたいこと
core::Loop()関数を利用側で定義してライブラリ側でmain()関数を定義して利用側でのmain()関数の記述を不要にする方法。クロスプラットフォームで行えるようにしたい。
試したこと、行ったこと

以下の提示コードのコメント部のように実装を変えて試した
ChatGPTを参考に提示コードを作成して動作を調べた
google等で検索

環境
OS: Windows 10
コンパイラ: MinGW, g++
利用ライブラリ：現状なし
下記のコードによるエラー
CMakeFiles/core.dir/src/entry.cpp.obj:entry.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `core::Loop()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

ソースコード
ライブラリ側
core.hpp
#ifndef ___CORE_HPP___
#define ___CORE_HPP___

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define EXPORT
#endif

namespace core
{
    EXPORT void Loop();
}

#endif

entry.cpp
#include "core.hpp"

namespace core
{
    EXPORT void Loop();  // Loop関数の宣言のみ
    //void Loop();  // Loop関数の宣言のみ
    
    int main()
    {
        Loop();
        //core::Loop();
        return 0;
    }
}

利用側
main.cpp
#include <core.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace core
{
    void Loop()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    }
}

/*
void core::Loop()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
*/


C++は、よく分らないのですが、デザインパターンのtemplate methodパターン (https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Method_%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3 ) みたいなことをやりたい、というのであっていますか？

どのようなコマンドラインでリンクしていますか。ライブラリはスタティックリンクでしょうかDLLでしょうか。

とりあえず main が namespace core の中にあるのはダメなのでは…？

任意のプラットフォーム任意のコンパイラで共通に通じる方法はおそらく普通に main() を含むソースファイルを提供するかオブジェクトファイルを提供するかの２つに１つだと思われます（ライブラリ形式で提供したのではダメ）
-- main.cpp --
namespace core {
    extern void Setup();
    extern int Loop();
}
int main() {
    core::Setup();
    while (core::Loop()==0);
    return 0;
}

ンで、この程度なら普通にあなたの作ったライブラリを使うプログラマに main() を実装させても大差ないというか、あなたがサンプルソースコードとして提供して末端プログラマがそれを読むことができるようにしておくほうがわかりやすいというか。
以下 TL;DR
解説書には main() が実行開始関数だと書かれています。この解説は、誤っているわけではありませんが正しくもありません。実際のプログラムにおいては main() の前にやらなければならない処理というのはいっぱいあり、その辺は各処理系で違う実装がされています。あくまでも「一般プログラマが書いた処理の開始位置」が main() なだけです。
Windows においては DLL ファイルには「実行開始権限」がありません。なので main() の前にやらなければならない各種処理を行わせる「エントリポイント」は EXE ファイル中に置かなければなりません。もし先のサンプル main.cpp を使って DLL ファイルを実装しようとしているなら DLL 中の main() が (EXE 中の main() より) 先に呼ばれることはありません。
ということで EXE (に相当する) 実行形式ファイル中に main() が必要です。これを静的ライブラリ (Linux 系だと ***.a 形式) で提供した場合、プログラマが自作の main() を作ってしまうと静的ライブラリの中の main() が使われることはありません（警告など一切なしに静的ライブラリ中の main() が無視されます）これを回避するには普通に c++ ソースコードで main() を提供してしまうほうが安全です。
あとコメントでも指摘されていますが c++ 言語仕様書 JIS X 14882:2003 の 3.6.1 関数 main

プログラムには、大域的な関数 main が含まれていなければならない。

ここの「大域的」は ::main() という意味なので、あなたの作った名前空間にある core::main() は開始関数になりえません。
ということでいろいろ書きましたが、この件を実用的なコスト（人件費など）で解決するのはいささか遠回りすぎな気がします。やらないほうが安上がりでしょう。オイラもやりたいと思いません（ main() を含むソースコードをサンプルとして提供するのならあり）
MFC は自立処理系相当の扱いになっていて、そもそも main() が無い（wWinMain から実行開始）のでこの辺の話は適用外だったりします。

コメント受けて追記

int main()関数は利用側で記述する形を取るほうが賢明といことでしょうか？

開発する際には表裏の事情がありますから、その辺はあなたの/あなたの上司の判断次第です。オイラが「利用者に main を書かせないプログラム開発をしろ」という案件を受けたら差し戻します。つまり上記質問のオイラの答えは Yes となります。が、オイラとあなたの事情は異なります。その辺の調査とか動作検証とかを「コスト」と思わなくてよい、技術的興味を満たすための知的作業ととらえるなら、やってみるといいでしょう。きっととても楽しく勉強になることと思います。
メタっぽいですが「本ライブラリを利用する際には main にこんな風に書くと良い」みたいなソースコードサンプルがついていると、利用者もプログラマですし、コンパイル済みオブジェクトファイルを添付するよりははるかに受けが良いはずです。結構重要。おそらくほとんどの利用者はそのサンプルそのまま使うでしょうし、それで「利用者に main を書かせない」という案件は満たせるはず。

ありがとうございます。一応確認ですかつまり、int main()関数は利用側で記述する形を取るほうが賢明といことでしょうか？

本当に作りたい物はライブラリと言うよりフレームワークなのでは無いでしょうか？
フレームワークもライブラリと一種じゃ無いかという話もありますが、ひとまずそれは置いといて、フレームワークのなかにはmain()のようなエントリーポイントをフレームワークで用意して、利用者はフレームワークで用意された関数を実装するという物があります。
一つの例として、Siv3Dというフレームワークを見つけました。このフレームワークは通常のエントリーポイント(main()またはWinMain())の代わりにMain()という関数を実装するようになっています。ただ、このフレームワークは単にライブラリをリンクするのでは無く、サンプルのMainを含んだテンプレートをつかってプログラミングするという形式のようです。このような形であれば、main()やWinMain()は利用者からは隠れた形になるため、本当の意味でクロスプラットフォームなプログラムを作ることが可能にしているのかも知れません。
ただ、Siv3D以外にこのような特徴を持つフレームワークは見つけられませんでした。Qt等のフレームワークと言われるもののほとんどはエントリーポイントでの呼び出し方だけをある程度決めているだけのようです。これは、フレームワークがエントリーポイントを持ってしまうと、同じようにエントリーポイントを持つフレームワークを使えなくなってしまうからかも知れません。
いずれにしても、やりたいことはSiv3Dがしているようなフレームワークの提供であれば、Siv3Dがどのようにしているかをみてみるといいかと思います。
